# Why IEnumerable<T> becomes empty after adding elements to a collection?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, ienumerable

- **I have an `IEnumerable<T>` when I iterate through it and add it's element to a list it becomes empty?**
- **Is there generally anything wrong about what I expect from the code?**

  ```
  public class Apple
  {
      private ICollection<Fruit> _fruits = new List<Fruit>();

      public void AddFruits(IEnumerable<Fruit> fruits)
      {
          if (fruits == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("fruits");
          foreach (var fruit in fruits)
          {
              _fruits.Add(fruit);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  The caller code:

  ```
  public void AddFruits(IEnumerable<Fruit> fruitsToAdd)
  {
      foreach (var apple in apples)
      {
          // Here fruitsToAdd has elements, fruitsToAdd.ToList() has two fruits.
          apple.AddFruits(fruitsToAdd);
          // Here fruitsToAdd has NO element!!, fruitsToAdd.ToList() is empty!
          // next iteration will not add any fruit to next apple since fruitsToAdd is empty.
      }
  }
  ```

**Update**

The ToList() solved the problem. The root of the problem was that the caller to AddFruits(IEnumerable fruitsToAdd) send fruitsToAdd that was like.

fruitsToAdd = obj.Fruits.Except(apples.Fruits);

Each time IEnumerable fruitsToAdd was Rest it run above statement. Which at next iteration run Except and thereby returned no fruits.

The right way is fruitsToAdd = obj.Fruits.Except(apples.Fruits).ToList(); Since we want one evaluation.

Comment: Because there's something wrong with your code, I expect. It's kinda hard to say any more without seeing *any* of your code...

Comment: So what exactly seems to be the problem? Can you show the code that produces an error?

Comment: You haven't shown what your `IEnumerable<T>` actually *is*. Please give us enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: If `apples` or `fruitsToAdd` are empty nothing will happen. Please be clear about what happens and what you expected.

Comment: @Henk I have updated with comments in the code what I expect.

Comment: @Jon Do you want to see the implementation of Fruit?

Comment: @Amir Rezaei, write a simple (one that compiles) console application that illustrates your problem. This way everything will be clear.

Comment: @Darin, the original class for Fruit is big class that is connect to many other classes. I can't just implement that in a console. Fruit is an example.

Comment: @Amir Rezaei, you will have to narrow down your problem. Currently your question is not clear. In the comments of the code you posted you are saying that *fruits has no elements*. But `fruitsToAdd` is an `IEnumerable<T>` and an `IEnumerable<T>` has not such notion of having or not elements. It's just a pointer to some data source you can enumerate over. And you haven't shown to what it points neither what does *it has elements* means. Currently your question is difficult to answer as you seem to be the only one able to reproduce some problem.

Comment: You haven't shown an error condition. I suspect that the original (now deleted) answer was correct. Are you trying to use `IEnumerator.Current` after you've just finished iterating over the list to inspect it? Is there an actual error in your code, or are you just looking at an `IEnumerable` in the debugger after a loop has finished iterating over it?

Comment: @jamietre Please read new code comment.

Comment: Something in the enumerator is removing the element in question when you operate on it - probably when you add it to something else. An example of this would be any heirarchical collection. If an elements membership in an enumeration is based on its "parent" property, e.g it is a child of one and only one thing, then adding it to something else will remove it from what is currently a member of. The structure of your collection is likely what's causing the problem, though probably it is by design.

Comment: actually @groo's answer is pretty much what I meant in my comment.

Comment: It's hard to tell what your use case even is here -- it's like "nonsense" code -- the kind you write when you're dreaming or something... -- I expect the technical problem is related to your original enumerable (perhaps it can only be enumerated once?).  You'll have to show us what that enumerable is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, try this:

```
public void AddFruits(IEnumerable<Fruit> fruitsToAdd)
{
    var fruitsToAddCopy = fruitsToAdd.ToList();  // add just this line

    foreach (var apple in apples)
    {           
        apple.AddFruits(fruitsToAddCopy);    // and change this        
    }
}
```

Without knowing the origin of your `fruitsToAdd` it's impossible to say more. Some `IEnumerable<>` can't be re-used. Others can.

Comment: Why can "Some IEnumerable<> can't be re-used. Others can. "

Comment: ToList() fixed the problem. The question is why?

Comment: The question is: What are you passing in? Most IEnumerables can be Reset, but it can be very expensive (IQueryable) . I can't think of one that is documented to be single use, something from a network stream would be. But your Apple class is irrelevant, look at the caller of AddFruits.

Comment: This code creates a new IList<T> that contains refs to the objects in your list. It's a copy, more or less, so it won't be affected by whatever code produces the original enumeration. I am guessing if you did this though: `var fruitsToAddCopy = fruitsToAdd.ToList()` you would find the same problem as before. The fact of using the same variable name just hides the original reference -- you are no longer acting on it once you do that.

Comment: @jamiet: I thought that it was obvious but you're right it is not entirely pure to reuse the parameter. Will edit.

Comment: @Henk: An `IEnumerable<T>` can't be reset (via the interface) - only an `IEnumerator<T>` can be.

Comment: @Henk I didn't mean there is anything wrong with the solution (I mean I still have no idea what the problem really is, this sounds like a feature of the object, and "solving" it may in fact break something else). I was just trying to explain to OP why it fixed the problem.

Comment: @Jon, right, sloppy use of words. I'll leave the comment up, I think the general idea still holds.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your question shouldn't exhibit such behavior, so I am presuming you tried to simplify it, but removed a lot of functionality from it.

What looks a bit suspicious is that your `_fruits` field is of type `ICollection<T>`. This interface is often used with custom collection implementations. Is it possible that, in the actual code, this field isn't instantiated with a `List<T>`, but rather with a custom implementation of that interface?

If you have a custom collection implementation, then it is perfectly possible for its `Add` method to do weird stuff (like removing an item from its previous "parent" collection before adding it to its new "parent"). Tree collections often do such things to simplify moving nodes around.

**[Edit]**

I am aware that this is not OPs actual problem, but I will nevertheless add an example to demonstrate that a custom collection implementation **can** in fact modify the input collection when its members are added to a different collection.

Let's say the `Fruit` class looks like this:

```
partial class Fruit
{
    private ICollection<Fruit> _children;
    private Fruit _parent;

    public String Name { get; set; }

    public Fruit()
    {
        _children = new FruitCollection(this);
    }

    public void AddFruits(IEnumerable<Fruit> fruits)
    {
        foreach (Fruit f in fruits)
            _children.Add(f);
    }

    public int NumberOfChildren
    {
        get { return _children.Count; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Fruit> GetFruits()
    {
        return _children.ToList();
    }
}
```

And there is a custom collection defined as:

```
partial class Fruit
{
    public class FruitCollection : Collection<Fruit>
    {
        private readonly Fruit _parent;
        public FruitCollection(Fruit parent)
        {
            _parent = parent;
        }

        protected override void InsertItem(int index, Fruit item)
        {
            // item already has a parent?
            if (item._parent != null)
            {
                // remove it from previous parent
                item._parent._children.Remove(item);
            }

            // set the new parent
            item._parent = _parent;

            base.InsertItem(index, item);
        }

        // other methods should be overriden in a similar way
    }
}
```

Then the following program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Fruit> abc = new List<Fruit>()
    {
        new Fruit() { Name = "a" },
        new Fruit() { Name = "b" },
        new Fruit() { Name = "c" }
    };

    Fruit apple = new Fruit() { Name = "apple" };
    apple.AddFruits(abc);

    Console.WriteLine("{0} has {1} children", apple.Name, apple.NumberOfChildren);


    // now try to add apples's children to
    // each of the following fruits
    List<Fruit> def = new List<Fruit>()
    {
        new Fruit() { Name = "d" },
        new Fruit() { Name = "e" },
        new Fruit() { Name = "f" }
    };

    foreach (Fruit f in def)
    {
        f.AddFruits(apple.GetFruits());
        Console.WriteLine("{0} has {1} children", f.Name, f.NumberOfChildren);
    }

    Console.Read();
}
```

Would print:

```
    apple has 3 children

    d has 3 children
    e has 0 children
    f has 0 children
```

Because `apple.GetFruits()` will return 0 after the first iteration.

By looking at the custom collection's source, it is hard to realize that `_children.Add(f)` in `AddFruits` in fact modifies the fruits previous parent collection.

Comment: The List is a .Net List. It's not a custom implementation.

Comment: Nice guess but _fruits is not the problem. fruitsToAdd is.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code to get it to compile and wrote a test.  Your list does not become empty after copying it's elements into the apples.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace ClassLibrary3
{
    [TestClass]
    public class Class1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void test()
        {
            var fruits = new List<Fruit> {new Fruit(), new Fruit(), new Fruit()};

            var lists = AddFruits(fruits);
            Assert.IsTrue(fruits.Count == 3);

        }

        public List<Apple> AddFruits(IEnumerable<Fruit> fruitsToAdd)
        {
            var apples = new List<Apple>
                             {
                                 new Apple(),
                                 new Apple()
                             };

            foreach (var apple in apples)
            {
                apple.AddFruits(fruitsToAdd);
            }
            return apples;
        }
    }

    public class Fruit 
    {
    }

    public class Apple
    {
        private ICollection<Fruit> _fruits = new List<Fruit>();

        public void AddFruits(IEnumerable<Fruit> fruits)
        {
            if (fruits == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("fruits");
            foreach (var fruit in fruits)
            {
                _fruits.Add(fruit);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Then the problem is the implementation of Fruit?